# Pegar a última posição de um split()

Tags: javascript

Preciso digitar um nome em um input e mostrar o nome da pessoa no seguinte formato:

SOBRENOME(última posição), Fulano de Tal.

Mas não estou conseguindo mostrar o nome nesse formato, e também não estou conseguindo utilizar o .toUpperCase() na váriavel "último", pois está dando erro.

```js
function formatar() {
  var nome = document.getElementById("nome").value;

  if (nome === "" || Number(nome)) {
    alert("Digite seu nome corretamente");
    document.getElementById("nome").value = "";
    document.getElementById("nome").focus();
    return;
  }

  var partes = nome.split(" ");
  var tam = partes.length;
  var text;
  var ultimo = partes.slice(-1);
  console.log(ultimo);

  for (i = 0; i < tam; i++) {
    text = ultimo.toUpperCase() + ", " + partes;

  }
  document.getElementById("formatacao").innerHTML = text;

}
```

```html
<input id="nome">
<button type="button" onclick="formatar()">Formatar</button>
<div id="formatacao"></div>
```

Comment: O problema no seu código, é que a variável `ultimo` é um array e não uma string, para acessar corretamente deveria fazer: `ultimo[0].toUpperCase()`

Answer (score 5):

**Sugestão:**

```
var partes = nome.split(' ');
var formatado = [partes.pop().toUpperCase(), partes.join(' ')].join(', ');
```

**A ideia é:**

- separar por espaços (como já tinhas)
- criar uma array com 2 posições
- na primeira posição colocar `partes.pop().toUpperCase()` (a ultima parte com letra grande)
- na segunda posição colocar o resto, re-colocando os espaços
- juntar as partes com virgula e espaço

**Exemplo:**

```js
function formatar() {
  var nome = document.getElementById("nome").value;

  if (nome === "" || Number(nome)) {
    alert("Digite seu nome corretamente");
    document.getElementById("nome").value = "";
    document.getElementById("nome").focus();
    return;
  }

  var partes = nome.split(' ');
  var formatado = [partes.pop().toUpperCase(), partes.join(' ')].join(', ');

  document.getElementById("formatacao").innerHTML = formatado;

}

document.querySelector("button").addEventListener('click', formatar);
```

```css
input {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<input id="nome" type="text" value="Antonio Manuel Antunes" />
<button>Formatar</button>
<div id="formatacao"></div>
```

Answer (score 4):

Abordagem usando regex:

```
var nome = "Jose da Silva Sauro";

function replacer(match, m1, m2){
    return m2.toUpperCase() + ', ' + m1;
}

nome.replace(/^(.+)\b(\w+)$/g, replacer); // "SAURO, Jose da Silva"
```

Comment: `\b`? Fim de palavra?

Comment: sim, a regex quebra a string em 2 partes: uma antes e outra depois do ultimo espaço

Comment: nunca usei com êxito o `\b`, bom ver um exemplo funcional

Answer (score 3):

Com o `split` divide, e depois pega no ultimo com `length-1` e junta com o array todo unido menos o ultimo, utilizando o `slice` para cortar o ultimo e o `join` para unir tudo de novo com espaços:

```js
var nome = "Luis Carlos Teixeira";
var nomes = nome.split(" ");
var nomeFinal = nomes[nomes.length-1].toUpperCase() + ", " + nomes.slice(0,-1).join(" ");

console.log(nomeFinal);
```

No seu código `ultimo.toUpperCase()` dá erro porque ultimo é um array e não uma string. Lembre-se que o [slice](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice) devolve um array.

Nas funções usadas temos:

- `split(" ")` parte uma string num array de acordo com o separador
  passado
- `slice(0, -1)` fica com o array todo menos o ultimo elemento
- `join (" ")` une o array em questão todo com espaços formando um
  novo texto(string)

Comment: e como eu faço para transformar esse array em uma string? Ou tenho que utilizar outro método para pegar a última posição do nome?

Comment: Se ja tem um array, o `partes` o ultimo nome é `partes[partes.length-1]`

Comment: Acontece que você tem uma string contida dentro de um array, então você não tem que transformar nada, bastaria acessar corretamente a posição do array, mas pessoalmente acho a resposta do @Isac mais segura e correta :)

Comment: ok, pode apenas me explicar por que (nomes.slice(0 , -1) me retorna a primeira e a segunda posição? -1 não deveria retornar a última? E para que serve o .join(" ")? Não entendi essas duas partes. Obrigado pela ajuda de todos :).

Comment: Sim eu posso completar também. O `slice(0, -1)` fica com o array todo menos a ultima posição, e o `join(" ")` une todo o array colando os valores com espaço, formando uma nova string.

Comment: Isac, mas por que slice(0) pega todo o array? Eu pensei que (0) pegasse a posição 1, ou é apenas o [0] que faz isso? Qual a diferença entre (0) e [0]?

Comment: Pega da `0` ao fim `-1`. O `0` indica de onde começa.

Answer (score 2):

> Melhorei sua função para testar nomes numéricos pois se inserisse `123 456 789`  ou `Fulano de Tal 123`iria aceitar.  [Créditos - Sergio](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/218689/valida%C3%A7%C3%A3o-dos-elementos-de-um-array-em-javascript/218691#218691)

```js
function formatar() {
  var nome = document.getElementById("nome").value;
  var partes = nome.split(' ');
  var tam = (partes.length-1);

  var ultimo = partes.slice(-1);
  console.log(ultimo);
  ultimo = ultimo.toString();
  
  var HasNumericStrings = partes.filter(function(i) {
    return !isNaN(i);
  }).length > 0;

  if (HasNumericStrings) {
    alert("Digite seu nome corretamente");
    document.getElementById("nome").value = "";
    document.getElementById("nome").focus();
  } else {
    document.getElementById("formatacao").innerHTML = ultimo.toUpperCase() + ", " + partes.slice(0,-1).join(" ");
  }

}
document.querySelector("button").addEventListener('click', formatar);
```

```html
<input id="nome" type="text" value="Fulano de Tal" />
<button>Formatar</button>
<div id="formatacao"></div>
```

- O método `split()` divide um objeto String em um array de strings ao separar a string em substrings
- A propriedade `length` define o número de elementos da matriz. Trata-se de um número uma unidade maior que o elemento mais alto definido em uma matriz.
- O método `filter()` cria um novo array com todos os elementos que passaram no teste implementado pela função fornecida.  [Leia mais](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filtro)
- O método `toUpperCase` retorna uma seqüência de caracteres onde todos os caracteres alfabéticos foram convertidos em maiúsculas.
- O método  `join(separador)` junta todos os elementos do array dentro de uma string. `separador` é opcional. Específica uma string para separar cada elemento da array. O separador é convertido em uma string se necessário. Se omitido, os elementos da array são separados com uma vírgula. Se o separador for uma string vazia, todos os elementos são juntados sem nenhum caracter entre eles.

  No caso em questão usamos um espaço `join(" ")`  [Leia mais](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join)

Comment: Tome cuidado Leo, sua resposta responde apenas parte do que foi perguntado

Comment: @MarceloBoni já tomei os devidos cuidados :)

Answer (score 0):

Somente uma variante da elegante solução @J.Guilherme(+1):

```
var n = "Jose da Silva Sauro";
n = n.replace(/(.+) (\w+)$/, function(_,a,b){return b.toUpperCase()+ ", "+ a});
```