# Validação dos elementos de um array em javascript

Tags: javascript

Tenho o script abaixo no qual não estou sabendo como impedir uma entrada cujo qualquer parte do nome seja somente numérico. Exemplo `Fulano de Tal 123` me retorna válido.

```js
 
function formatar() {
  var nome = document.getElementById("nome").value;
  var partes = nome.split(' ');
  var IsNumericString = partes.filter(function(i){
    return isNaN(i);
  }).length > 0;

  if (IsNumericString == 0 ) {
    alert("Digite seu nome corretamente");
  }else{
    alert("Nome OK");
  }

}
document.querySelector("button").addEventListener('click', formatar);
```

```html
<input id="nome" type="text" value="Fulano de Tal" />
<button>Formatar</button>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Estavas a fazer uma comparação `.value > 0` e isso dá um booleano, assim quando fazes depois o `if(... == 0)` isso nunca vai dar verdadeiro pois o `IsNumericString` é booleano e não length/numérico.

```js
function formatar() {
  var nome = document.getElementById("nome").value;
  var partes = nome.split(' ');
  var HasNumericStrings = partes.filter(function(i) {
    return !isNaN(i);
  }).length > 0;

  if (HasNumericStrings) {
    alert("Digite seu nome corretamente");
  } else {
    alert("Nome OK");
  }

}
document.querySelector("button").addEventListener('click', formatar);
```

```html
<input id="nome" type="text" value="Fulano de Tal" />
<button>Formatar</button>
```

Comment: Perfeito!!!!! alias, como sempre né!!! Aproveita e implementa essa validação também  na sua resposta nesse post  https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/218609/pegar-a-%C3%BAltima-posi%C3%A7%C3%A3o-de-um-split/

Answer (score 1):

Aconselho fazer esta validação utilizando **regex**, segue o exemplo:

*Este código valida o nome como um todo, logo se houver um número no nome vai pedir para digitar novamente:

```js
function formatar() {
  var nome = document.getElementById("nome").value;
  var regex = nome.match(/\d+/g);
  if (regex != null) {
    alert("Digite seu nome corretamente");
  } else {
    alert("Nome OK");
  }
}
document.querySelector("button").addEventListener('click', formatar);
```

```html
<input id="nome" type="text" value="Fulano de Tal" />
<button>Formatar</button>
```

Neste outro snippet as partes são validadas independentemente, ou seja, se houver um bloco somente de números(`Fulano de Tal 123`), pede para digitar novamente:

```js
function formatar() {
  var nome = document.getElementById("nome").value;
  var partes = nome.split(' ');
  var isNumeric = false;
  partes.map(function(item) {
    if (/^\d+$/.test(item)) isNumeric = true;
  })
  if (isNumeric) {
    alert("Digite seu nome corretamente");
  } else {
    alert("Nome OK");
  }
}
document.querySelector("button").addEventListener('click', formatar);
```

```html
<input id="nome" type="text" value="Fulano de Tal" />
<button>Formatar</button>
```

Comment: Realmente foi difícil escolher qual resposta deveria aceitar, mas sou fã do Sergio e isso diz tudo  :)

Comment: @LeoCaracciolo hahahaha, somos fãs  =)